# What is the difference between a dictionary and a Map in Javascript 6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How is a Map different from a dictionary/object?

In other words, what is the difference between `let x = {}` and `let x = new Map()` ?

Comment: "The Map object is a simple key/value map. **Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value**." -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: That page from Mozilla also has a section "objects and Maps compared".

Comment: The biggest difference is that a `Map` can use any value as a key (such as another Object) where as using `{}` requires a string as the key.  In fact, a Map can contain separate items with keys of `"1"` and `1`, but a plain object cannot.  And, of course, a Map object has built in methods that apply to a Map object that `{}` does not have.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind: a Map instance *is also an object*, and can have properties etc. just like any other object. You can create a Map instance and give the object named function methods for example.

Comment: I don't understand the constant references to MDN. The [*language specification*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-map-objects) is pretty clear (on this at least) and has the benefit if being the definitive reference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**[Objects and maps compared](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared)** (from MDN):

> Objects are similar to Maps in that both let you set keys to values,
>   retrieve those values, delete keys, and detect whether something is
>   stored at a key. Because of this (and because there were no built-in
>   alternatives), Objects have been used as Maps historically; however,
>   there are important differences between Objects and Maps that make
>   using a Map better:
>
> - An Object has a prototype, so there are default keys in the map.
>     This could be bypassed by using map = Object.create(null) since ES5,
>     but was seldomly done.
> - The keys of an Object are Strings and Symbols, where they can be
>     any value for a Map.
> - You can get the size of a Map easily while you have to manually
>     keep track of size for an Object.
>
> This does not mean you should use Maps everywhere, objects still are
>   used in most cases. Map instances are only useful for collections, and
>   you should consider adapting your code where you have previously used
>   objects for such. Objects shall be used as records, with fields and
>   methods. If you're still not sure which one to use, ask yourself the
>   following questions:
>
> - Are keys usually unknown until run time, do you need to look them up dynamically?
> - Do all values have the same type, and can be used interchangeably?
> - Do you need keys that aren't strings?
> - Are key-value pairs often added or removed?
> - Do you have an arbitrary (easily changing) amount of key-value pairs?
> - Is the collection iterated?
>
> Those all are signs that you want a Map for a collection. If in
>   contrast you have a fixed amount of keys, operate on them
>   individually, and distinguish between their usage, then you want an
>   object.

Comment: Another thing that may be of significant importance is that the Map contents are ignored by `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: Please make sure to format your quotation of my MDN text as a quote :-)